# Multiple accelerometers on a raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, accelerometer, storing-data

I want to use 4 accelerometers in an experiment. I will be using a raspberry pi. How can I distinguish the data from each sensor?

This is the accelerometer I am using
http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/9054665/

There are 2 addresses... does this mean that only 2 accelerometers can be connected to the raspberry pi?

Comment: That really depends on the sensors.  What is the part number, what does its datasheet say about interfacing it?  Anyone helping you will need to know that to even start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially correct with your assumption. You can only connect two of those to a single I2C bus because the address selection pin on the device gives you two I2C addresses to work with.

To get over that you need to use some sort of bus multiplexing like
I2C Multiplexer for the Raspberry Pi or choose different chip to have two more.

That is the Multiplexer:
https://www.tindie.com/products/land_boards/i2c-multiplexer-for-the-raspberry-pi-rpi-i2c-hub/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwtJzLBRC7ARIsAGMkOAnhjKFbSYeAyNId95C7TkhljkFLbamsbI0yzYC2Lta5JC1zexQsUnMaAm4MEALw_wcB

Comment: but is it then possible to get all the data sync?

Comment: As much as it is possible to achieve data sync with 4 separate devices on the same I2C bus - on both cases you need to access each device separately, but when using some multiplexer you need to write the multiplexer control register for selection before issuing a read to desired device.

Comment: I want to be able to read data from all 4 accelerometers at the same time

Comment: I2C is a serial bus, there is no such time as on the same time when dealing with serial communication (this holds true also for parallel buses in fact). You can do at the same time parallel reading when using FPGA to perform 4 parallel reads, but that would mean writing VHDL or Verilog to achieve such a feat.

Comment: What is the time window you much achieve to get all the 4 samples from the sensors?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the pin labels on the photo of that part, it's an I2C interface. This interface is typically used to attach lower-speed devices to processors over short distances, and is a synchronous serial protocol. You'll need to read up on interfacing I2C to the Pi. But you can certainly do it. I'd start with getting one up and running. Then get two running, which will teach you how to select a particular part to read/write.

Assuming a Pi 3, you have pins that are dedicated to I2C.  To connect more I2C devices, you'll have to get inventive.  But [a tutorial like this one](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi-spi-and-i2c-tutorial) might help you get started with the first one or two.